# Angular send JSPDF file to API to store it in database

Tags: angular

I have a form in my project where I enter user data and generate JSPDF file with these data and I need to make send the PDF generated file to the 'report' FormControl to send it to the API so I can store it in the database.

I have a blob variable that will carry the blob, when I submit the form I am calling the exportHtmlToPDF() function the converts the div to PDF and output it as blob to the blob variable

```
blob: any;

createUserForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    'name': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(100)]),
    'gender': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
    'date_of_birth': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
    'identity': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(9), Validators.maxLength(14)]),
    'patient_id': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(100)]),
    'test': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(100)]),
    'result': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
    'collect_date': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
    'report_date': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
    'branch': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(100)]),
    'reference_range': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
    'lab_director': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(100)]),
    'qr_url': new FormControl(this.qrCode),
    'qr_link': new FormControl(this.qrLink),
    'report': new FormControl(null)
});

onSubmit() {
    this.exportHtmlToPDF();

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('name', this.createUserForm.get('name')?.value);
    formData.append('gender', this.createUserForm.get('gender')?.value);
    formData.append('date_of_birth', this.createUserForm.get('date_of_birth')?.value);
    formData.append('identity', this.createUserForm.get('identity')?.value);
    formData.append('patient_id', this.createUserForm.get('patient_id')?.value);
    formData.append('test', this.createUserForm.get('test')?.value);
    formData.append('result', this.createUserForm.get('result')?.value);
    formData.append('collect_date', this.createUserForm.get('collect_date')?.value);
    formData.append('report_date', this.createUserForm.get('report_date')?.value);
    formData.append('branch', this.createUserForm.get('branch')?.value);
    formData.append('reference_range', this.createUserForm.get('reference_range')?.value);
    formData.append('lab_director', this.createUserForm.get('lab_director')?.value);
    formData.append('qr_url', this.createUserForm.get('qr_url')?.value);
    formData.append('qr_link', this.createUserForm.get('qr_link')?.value);
    formData.append('report', this.blob);

    this._UsersService.storeUser(formData).subscribe(data => {
        if (data == "Customer Added Successfully") {
            alert('customer added!')
        }
    });
}

public exportHtmlToPDF() {
    let data = document.getElementById('pdf')!;

    html2canvas(data).then(canvas => {

        let docWidth = 208;
        let docHeight = canvas.height * docWidth / canvas.width;

        const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        let doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
        let position = 0;
        doc.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, position, docWidth, docHeight);

        this.blob = doc.output('blob');
    });
}
```

Comment: @AndrewE I must object in the strongest terms. Base64 `data:` URIs _are very inefficient_ should not be used for passing around objects larger than a couple of kilobytes. JS has the `Blob` type and `URL.createObjectURL` for very good reasons - the OP should be using those instead.

Comment: @Dai Can you modify my code in an answer please?

Comment: @OsamaAmr You're not my client. [You can read the documentation for `HTMLCanvasElement.toBlob` yourself.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob)

Comment: What, exactly does `document.getElementById('pdf')` return?

Comment: Hmm, apparently `jsPDF`'s `addImage` function accepts a `HTMLCanvasElement` directly. There is no need to use `toBlob` nor `toDataURL`: https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-addImage.html#~addImage

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you generating a PDF at all if it only contains a single image? Why not just pass around the image `Blob`?

Comment: @Dai Thanks for the heads up, if the object was super large, I would never convert it to base64, however I was unaware that base64 should not be used for objects larger than a couple of kilobytes, you learn something new everyday :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate to have to repeat myself, but: **DO NOT USE `toDataURL` FOR ANYTHING LARGER THAN A FEW KILOBYTES**:

- Generating `data:` URIs is sloooow and blocks the browser's UI/render thread (e.g. my browser on my beefy modern machines freezes for about 5-7 seconds when it saves a `Blob` containing a 4K-wallpaper-sized JPEG image to a Base64 `data:` URI, whereas using `URL.createObjectURL` is *instantaneous*.
- Base64 encoding increases the size of your binary data by 33% (as it uses 4 bytes of ASCII text to represent 3 raw binary bytes).
- Every time a `data:` URI is used it has to be validated, parsed, decoded, and its inner binary data copied into a new destination buffer (internal to the browser). This is a whole slew of inefficencies. Using `Blob` avoids that entirely.
- You cannot use `data:` URIs to directly upload binary data unless your server-side or back-end logic is specifically programmed to handle it (also there's no official MIME type that represents a `data:` URI alone, and the old fallback of `application/octet-stream` isn't appropriate either), whereas if you pass a `Blob` to `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest` it will perfectly upload/transfer the binary data *with* the correct MIME Content-Type too!

---

...with that out of the way:

`<canvas>` supports exporting image data as a `Blob` object which you can pass directly into a `FormData` object for `multipart/form-data` binary uploads (just like `<input type="file" />`) - as well as for *direct* `PUT` requests where the request body's payload *is* the raw `Blob` data.

[Apparently jsPDF's `addImage` function](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-addImage.html#%7EaddImage) accepts a `HTMLCanvasElement` directly, so there is no need to use `toBlob` (and especially not `toDataURL`, eww).

```
async function exportHtmlToPDF() {

    const pdfElement = document.getElementById('pdf') as /* What element is it? */ | null;
    if( !pdfElement ) throw new Error( "Couldn't find 'pdf' element." );

    const canvas = await html2canvas( pdfElement );

    let docWidth = 208;
    let docHeight = canvas.height * docWidth / canvas.width;
    
    const doc = new jsPDF( 'p', 'mm', 'a4' );
    
    doc.addImage(canvas, 'PNG', /*x:*/ 0, /*y:*/ 0, docWidth, docHeight);
    
    const pdfBlob = doc.output( 'blob' );
    
    const uploadResponse = await fetch( '/pdf-upload-handler', { method: 'PUT', body: pdfBlob } );
    console.log( uploadResponse );
}
```

However I noticed that your program doesn't actually need to generate a PDF. The PDF you're generating is just wrapping an existing PNG image, so why not just upload the PNG image and skip the (slooowwww) client-side PDF generation?

```
async function exportHtmlToPng() {

    const pdfElement = document.getElementById('pdf') as /* What element is it? */ | null;
    if( !pdfElement ) throw new Error( "Couldn't find 'pdf' element." );

    const canvas = await html2canvas( pdfElement );
    
    canvas.toBlob( gotBlob, 'image/png' );
}

async function gotBlob( pngBlob: Blob | null ) {
    
    if( !pngBlob ) return;

    const uploadResponse = await fetch( '/png-image-upload-handler', { method: 'PUT', body: pngBlob } );
    console.log( uploadResponse );
}
```

Better yet, here's a version with a `Promise` adapter for `toBlob`:

```
async function exportHtmlToPng() {

    const pdfElement = document.getElementById('pdf') as /* What element is it? */ | null;
    if( !pdfElement ) throw new Error( "Couldn't find 'pdf' element." );

    const canvas = await html2canvas( pdfElement );
    
    const pngBlob = await getBlob( canvas, 'image/png' );

    const uploadResponse = await fetch( '/png-image-upload-handler', { method: 'PUT', body: pngBlob } );

    console.log( uploadResponse );
}

function getBlob( canvas: HTMLCanvasElement, type: string ): Promise<Blob> {
    
    return new Promise( function( resolve, reject ) {
        
        canvas.toBlob( function( blob ) => {
            
            if( blob ) resolve( blob );
            else reject( "Failed to create Blob from Canvas." );
            
        }, type );
        
    } );
}
```

Comment: Iam not generating just PNG image, I am generating DIV full of data and HTML and CSS

Comment: @OsamaAmr Yes, but in the code you posted you were just rendering all of that to a single `<canvas>` as a raster image and adding that to your PDF. You weren't adding any other text or layout data to the PDF. If you are then you need to update your initial post to show all relevant code

Comment: I have a similar problem in Angular and i am trying to implement what you explain. But I am unable to send the gerated blob data of the pdf to my java rest backend. Would you assist me If I open a new question?

Comment: @YannickMussche Are you still having issues?